# How can I translate "Who cares for the carers?"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Trying for a pithy bit of Latin to echo "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?"

Carers as in doctors / nurses etc.

Sorry, to clarify...

My understanding / interpretation is that "who guards the guards?" is that it is a cleverly circular idea that you might have a population of civilians/prisoners who might have an army or guards looking after / guarding them, but that the guards themselves also need protecting, or keeping an eye on (in case they stray from their duty).

I am looking for an echo of this idea in Latin to end an essay. The essay is about difficult working conditions for doctors, stress, and professional burnout, and what I would like to get to is something like "who cares for the caregivers". It's not simply who is giving medical care to the medical profession, ideally broader about those who give care, could be family, nurses, doctors.

Comment: Although I think I understand your question (see answer below), it might be worth formulating it more specifically.

Comment: Please try to do some research of your own. This is not "translate my Latin for me", it's "I have a question about Latin, please answer". This one is a superset of that one, which makes the line blurry, but in this case it seems like you haven't even looked up "How to say doctor in Latin."

Comment: If there is no need to use the same root for both words (_care_ and _care_-givers) AND you value using an attested sentence or a cliche, it is worth noting that _medice, cura te ipsum_ is in Lc 4,23. It excludes family (_stricto sensu_) but encompasses a broader kind of care.

Comment: How about "those who give solace" as in "quis solatus ipsos solatores" .. apologies I never got further than "Cacelius est in horto" at school!

Comment: That would work, though this word is more commonly found with the prefix *con*: *Quis consolabitur ipsos consolatores?*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to modify the original phrase, here are some possibilities:

> Quis medebitur ipsis medicis?
>
> Quis curabit ipsos curatores?

Note that *medicus* has a more restricted sense than English *caregiver*, and a *curator* is more like a *superintendent*.

The more I think of it, though, the more I think you should **just keep the original phrase**: remember that *custos* has many extended senses, among which (according to [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcustos)) *a guard, watch, preserver, keeper, overseer, protector, defender, attendant*.

Comment: Might be worth expanding on the limited sense of *medicus* in Latin, since that seems to be closest to what the OP is asking about?

Comment: I went with Quis curabit ipsos curatores? as the closest I could get, thanks brianpck

Comment: Quis servabit ipsos servatores?

Answer (score 4):

I second @brianpck's recommendation of *Quis medebit ipsis medicis*, if you're talking specifically about medical professionals and medical care. My sense of *custodire* is that most of its uses are in the sense of protecting others from something rather than protecting the thing itself, so I myself probably wouldn't use the original phrase. (However, I'm only familiar with a small part of the literature, so I could be wrong.)

Another option, if you're looking for something more general than "Who will give medical care to the medical professionals?", might be *Quis tuebitur ipsis tutoribus?*: "Who watches over those who watch over?" or "Who protects the protectors"?"

*Tutor* in Lewis Elementary is defined in part as as

> 1. a watcher, protector, defender
> 2. [in law] a guardian, tutor, guardian of the person

and *tueor* as

> 1. to look at, gaze upon, behold, watch, view, regard, consider, examine
> 2. [figuratively] to keep in mind, regard
> 3. to look to, care for, watch over, keep up, uphold, maintain, support, guard, preserve, defend, protect